# Error with mysqli->prepare - Malformed communication packet

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My code was working fine, but today I am getting this error using mysqli-prepare
"Malformed communication packet"

Code:

```
<?php
  require_once('conntele.php');
  $sql_type = "SELECT id_tipo_identificacion, descripcion FROM tipo_identificacion WHERE estado_registro = 'A'";
  echo "Using Mysqli->query<br>";
  if ($res_type = $mysqli->query($sql_type)) {
    while($row_type = $res_type->fetch_assoc()){
      echo "type: ".$row_type['id_tipo_identificacion']." description: ".$row_type['descripcion']."<br>";
    }
  }

  echo "<br>";
  echo "Using Mysqli->prepare<br>";
  if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql_type)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $result_type = $stmt->get_result();
    print_r($stmt);
    while($row_type_iden = $result_type->fetch_assoc()){
      echo "type: ".$row_type_iden['id_tipo_identificacion']." description: ".$row_type_iden['descripcion']."<br>";
    }
    $stmt->close();
  }

  $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Error:

```
Using Mysqli->query
type: 1 description: RUC
type: 2 description: Cedula
type: 3 description: Pasaporte
type: 4 description: Venta a Consumidor Final
type: 5 description: Identificacion del Exterior

Using Mysqli->prepare
mysqli_stmt Object ( [affected_rows] => -1 [insert_id] => 0 [num_rows] => 0 [param_count] => 0 [field_count] => 2 
[errno] => 1835 [error] => Malformed communication packet [error_list] => 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [errno] => 1835 [sqlstate] => HY000 [error] => Malformed communication packet ) ) 
[sqlstate] => HY000 [id] => 57 )
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in
/prepare.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in 
/prepare.php on line 17
```

PHP Version 7.2.29

How can I solve this problem

Comment: Most likely you will need t update your PHP version (which is End of Life in 20 days anyway)